# To prove the equality about expectation of a random variable X

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am stuck on this problem for some time now. It says if $X$ is non-negative random variable with density function $f$ and if $r(u)=\int_{u}^{\infty}f(t)dt$, then

$E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X\geq u)du=\int_{0}^{\infty}r(u)du$.

What I have observed is $r(u)=1-F(u)$, where $F$ is cumulative distribution function of X.

This means $r'(u)=-F'(u)=-f(u)$.

So, $E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}-xr'(x)dx$. But this approach doesn't seem working. Any hint. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can continue from where you stopped using integration by parts.

Comment: The usual approach is to start with $E[X] = \int_0^\infty x f(x) \, dx$, substitute $x = \int_0^x \, dt$, and use Fubini's theorem to exchange the integrals.

Comment: Write $X = \int_0^\infty 1(X\geq x) dx$. Now take expectations and justify interchanging the integrals.

Comment: Yup...got it..